# Check for locked liquidity programatically on BSC

Tags: web3js, bsc

Is there any way to check the locked liquidity for a specific pair? (Let's say token X / BNB). Currently, I can get the token liquidity by getting the pair between both (using the factory) and then getting the balance. But I'm not sure how I can do to check if the liquidity is token (contract locked). I'm working on nodejs and using web3 or ethers.js (both).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the solution mate ?